# Dynamic Array undefined error in IE

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to generate dynamic Control. It is working on FF but IE gives error:

> `divcntrl[i]` is undefined.

Please check the following code:

```
 var mc=document.getElementById("maindiv");
    var divcntrl = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i<10;i++) {
      divcntrl[i]=document.createElement("div");\\error here
    divcntrl[i].setAttribute("id","div"+ i);
      mc.appendChild(divcntrl[i]);
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535934(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as `<div1>` element. Running your code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WAPX3/), it runs without errors so the problem is somewhere else. Are you cached with a bad version of the file?

```
var mc=document.getElementById("maindiv");
var divcntrl = new Array();
for(var i=0; i<10;i++) {
    divcntrl[i]=document.createElement("div");
    divcntrl[i].innerHTML = i;
    mc.appendChild(divcntrl[i]);
}​
```

I think you would want to code it more like

```
var mc = document.getElementById("maindiv");
var divcntrl = [];
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "div" + i;
    div.innerHTML = i;
    divcntrl.push(div);
    mc.appendChild(div);
}​
```

Comment: Your problem is something else since that code will run and it has been proven to run. Clean your cache, make sure you have all the correct files loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `DIV` element, NOT a `"div"+i` element, since `"div"+i` is not part of any HTML specification ("div1" is not an HTML element). Are you confusing "div" and "id"?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line

```
divcntrl[i]=document.createElement("div" + i);
```

Just try this:

```
var divElt = document.createElement("div");
divElt.id = i;
divcntrl[i] = divElt;
```